# Extract date from inside a string with Python

Tags: python, string, split

I have the following string, while the first letters can differ and can also be sometimes two, sometimes three or four.

```
PR191030.213101.ABD
```

I want to extract the `191030` and convert that to a valid date.

```
filename_without_ending.split(".")[0][-6:]

PZA191030_392001_USB
```

Sometimes it looks liket his

This solution is not valid since this is also might differ from time to time. The only REAL pattern is really the first six numbers.

How do I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: With the rules you gave it works every time no? Get you give us a counter example when it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the first 6 digits using a pattern an a capturing group

```
^[A-Z]{2,4}(\d{6})\.
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]{2,4}` Match 2, 3 or 4 uppercase chars
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\d{6}` Match 6 digits
- `)\.` Close group and match trailing dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AKRo8R/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/pLW08o)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"^[A-Z]{2,4}(\d{6})\."
test_str = "PR191030.213101.ABD"
matches = re.search(regex, test_str)

if matches:
    print(matches.group(1))
```

Output

```
191030
```

Comment: thank you, really advanced solution. Hope its ok when you accept the one with the list comprehension since I feel more comfortable using that ;-)

Comment: @DataMastery Of course, no problem at all. You should select the solution that works for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
a = 'PR191030.213101.ABD'
int(''.join([c for c in a if c.isdigit()][:6]))
```

Output:

```
191030
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done by:

```
filename_without_ending.split(".")[0][2::]
```

This splits the string from the 3rd letter to the end.

Answer (score 0):

## Since first letters can differ we have to ignore alphabets and extract digits.

## So using re module (for regular expressions) apply regex pattern on string. It will give matching pattern out of string.

## '\d' is used to match [0-9]digits and + operator used for matching 1 digit atleast(1/more).

## findall() will find all the occurences of matching pattern in a given string while #search() is used to find matching 1st occurence only.

import re

str="PR191030.213101.ABD"

print(re.findall(r"\d+",str)[0])

print(re.search(r"\d+",str).group())